Input file specified two times
I am using shell in Jupyter with Python programming Language. When I use to prepare a dataset, I fail to complete it on sorting by column and case sensitive.
The line is like this:
!head -n 5 $filename | sort -f -t' ' -k2

I have tried so many things to solve it, but my bad. I can not get out from this problem yet. I don't know much about the error and stack on the same place.

For more specify the problem, I am attaching a screen shot of my code.
I tried
!head -n 5 $filename | sort -f -t\ -k2

But nothing helps me to overcome from this error: Input file specified two times.

In your screenshot, it jumps near the bottom from the twelfth cell run to around fifty. We cannot see what you ran in between that might have messed things up. Please restart the kernel and run all. Most likely if you do that, the issue will go away because what you did in the interim will not occur again. However, if you are really trying to understand what happened, although it is likely something unexciting, be advised cannot help you with hidden state problems without you sharing everything that was run.

If it is still giving you issues after that, maybe check out here, especially what neoh4x0r and ignorediacritics say. Your sort may not be exactly the flavor expected?
